# Data not "sticking" to my DataFrame when I append it to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to programming and data science. Here's a strange problem I came across. I'm doing feature engineering on a DataFrame filled with information about movies. I have actors count vectorized for each movie and I'm predicting metacritic score.

Originally, I tried to also replace the Actors column with an aggregate score for each member of the series of lists. For instance, if four people were listed in a movie, I'd take the average of their Metascores (their own average Metascore) and average that, using the code below. Some actors wouldn't have values or some movies might have no actors listed, so if I ran into those problems, I would just use annp.nan (Later, I would change this to a 666.666 to easily remove).

At first this seemed to have worked. It gave me better models (though only when I still count vectorized the Actors column). But this may have been a fluke. I noticed some of the data was strange looking. So I tried to reproduce the problem.

For this code:
Actors is a column of lists, each with four actor names.
actors_df is a DataFrame of two columns, one of the actor names and one of their corresponding average Metacritic scores. 
morta_list is just a list so I could keep track of what was going on.

```
morta = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset=['Metascore', 'imdbID']).copy()
morta['ActorAvg'] = 0.

morta_list = []
for index, m in enumerate(morta.Actors):
    s=0
    den = 0
    for p in m:
        for n in zip(actors_df.name.values, actors_df.avgscore):
            if p.lower() == n[0]:
                s = s + n[1]
                den = den + 1
    if den == 0:
        morta.ActorAvg[index]=666.666
        morta_list.append(666.666)
    else:
        morta.ActorAvg[index]=s/den
        morta_list.append(s/den)
```

However, later, when I checked my new column, I was getting weird results:

```
morta['ActorAvg'].sum()
```

gave me 6344793.712, but

```
morta[['ActorAvg']].sum()
```

gave me 0. There were other discrepancies as well. For instance:

[values don't match up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tilm6.png)

[won't sum correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7rj0.png)

I couldn't get the new ActorAvg column to reproduce 6344793.712 as a sum when it was in the new DataFrame.

I know this is complicated and I'm not sure I'm explaining it well, but can anyone help me get this information to "stick"?

Comment: Couple of things. Detach the problem from your specific case (I'm totally guilty of not doing this) and don't post links to external resources that might expire.

Comment: A lot of pandas functions have an `inplace` argument.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time posting a question on here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.loc[row_index, col_name] = value`. Otherwise you're assigning a value to a slice of the dataframe. More info: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/